# mysql restore database

Tags: mysql

I am try to restore a big database from file using this command

source /path/to/database/file

it is return this error:

Failed to open file '/path/to/database/file', error: 27

the .sql file size 4.1G

Answer (score 1):

If that's a file created by the mysqldump command, you'll probably want to run it using the mysql program.  That'll be something like `mysql -u <username> -p <databasename>`

The [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) command is another command you might wanna look at.